# What should be preferred way to keep configuration properties.. .properties file or storing configuration in a database table?

Tags: java, .net, jakarta-ee, web, configuration

I have a requirement in my project to keep some configuration properties in a .properties file (server_config.properties) so that it can be altered without hard coding key-value pairs e.g server_url = http://www.mydomain.com
server_port : 5000    ....etc  and there can be 100's of properties in this file.

I am thinking why not keep the key-value pair configuration in database table and read it from there.

Can you guys please share your experiences of using both approaches and mention what are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

In my opinion , I think keeping in a database table should be better approach, in that way  I can change the values in database and they can be loaded dynamically into server via JMX calls , and could be shared by multiple instances of my application.

Please share.

Comment: Brace yourselves, [HighCore](http://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore) comments about *.Net is the best and Java sucks* are coming...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you mispelled my nickname, and no I never said ".Net is the best"...

Comment: My project is in Java but I think the question is platform independent and good answer my come from any side as all projects may need configuration management.

Comment: @supernova not really, .Net has it's own built-in mechanisms to deal with that, as opposed to forcing you to reinvent the wheel all the time. In ASP.Net Web applications, you have a `web.config` file which allows you to define all sorts of configurations for your application, and which forces the application to reload everytime it's modified.

Comment: @HighCore what makes you think Java doesn't have these mechanisms?

Comment: Look at the owner of the data.  If it is a dba that you want to allow to configure then put in db.  If it is the web or app admin then the config.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends: are these configuration values which you might want the user of the system to be able to change? 
Then, YES, database (and you can add a web page to create/retrieve/update/delete later). 
However, if these are more "hidden" configuration values for the system manager (you), then I would not see any good reason to have them in the database.
For example, you can't specify parameters related to the database which are stored in the database.
Sure, the configuration file might get large, but 100's of lines is not really that big, and you can split it into multiple configuration files if you'd like (server_config.properties, database_config.properties, user_config.properties, etc) and easily add comments.
However, on the database "pro's", I would add that you can track who modified a parameter (if your webpage has user login information).
When you write "server_config.properties", then that sounds like Java and a `new Properties()`.